# Does TextToSpeech API in android need internet connection to work?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am want to use  TextToSpeech API  in android, does the application need internet connection to convert the text to speech ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install TTS data. Users are prompted to install it if they don't have it. Until you have the data the speech cannot occur and the device needs an Internet connection to download and install the data.

Source : http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-using-the-text-to-speech-engine/

Comment: when are the prompted to install it ?

Comment: Please examine link above. It's really detailed.

Comment: can you help me in this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497552/synthesizetofile-failed-not-bound-to-tts-engine-when-using-texttospeech-in-an

Answer (score 0):

While calling `createSoundFile` you do need internet. However if you call `addSpeech` before calling `speak` then you do not need internet. In another word, if you speak from a file then no internet is needed.

Comment: I don't undertand you, synthesizing needs internet connection!