# synthesizeToFile failed: not bound to TTS engine , when using TextToSpeech in android

Tags: android, text-to-speech, speechsynthesizer

I am using `Android TextToSpeech API`, I want to save the convert text2speech as a file on the SD-card memory, but I got the error:

```
 synthesizeToFile failed: not bound to TTS engine
```

My code to use TTS is :

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {


        if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
                tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

                if(getIntent() != null){
                    if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null){
                        String d = getIntent().getExtras().getString("data");

                        String data[] = d.split("-");
                        bookName = data[0];
                        loadPage(data[0], Integer.parseInt(data[1]));
                    }
                }
                Log.d("TTS","Data is loaded");

            }
            else {
                Intent installTTSIntent = new Intent();
                installTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(installTTSIntent);
            }
        }
    }
```

where inside the `loadPage()` function a call the `synthesizeToFile` function as below :

```
String tempDestFile = appTmpPath.getAbsolutePath() +"/"+ fileName;
tts.synthesizeToFile(speakTextTxt, myHashRender, tempDestFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait until after `onInit` is called before you can call `speak, synthesizeToFile` etc... put your `loadPage` method in `onInit` after checking for success there.